# OAuth: How to add magento product using oauth rest api from external php script

Tags: magento-1.7, api, oauth

I'm new in Magento, I want to add Magento product from my CodeIgniter (external php script).

I have created Web_Services->OAuth_Consumers and get key and Secret.

what is the next step? (also set REST Attribute, REST Roles)

I try googling but not getting proper answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the admin account for the backend it will be very useful as admin will have the permission already set up for adding products to the system. Lets assume you have access to the admin user.

This is a sample code which will add a product to the system using OAuth as admin

```
<?php
/**
* Example of simple product POST using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
*/
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://magentohost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $productData = json_encode(array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
            'weight'            => 1,
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => 'Simple Product',
            'description'       => 'Simple Description',
            'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
            'price'             => 99.95,
            'tax_class_id'      => 0,
        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

This code snippet is courtesy of Magento REST api documentation. Link [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#root)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Well I was just being helpful and pointing him to right directions in searching answers. This is a very basic questions a lot of people starting out ask. It's even in the stackoverflow guidelines to make sure you have ample research before asking the question. But I guess I should include some more explanation before answering.

Comment: i have googled for answer but not getting proper way or any tutorial. what i need to do to insert product to magento (using oauth) from external php project (which is not in magento) ?

Comment: Hey I have updated the answer. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: `{"messages":{"error":[{"code":401,"message":"oauth_problem=token_rejected"}]}}` .....

Comment: getting error I am trying to add product from outside of magento , I have give permission to guest but its now working.

Comment: I have set REST Attribute and REST Role for guest to allow all, and working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey glad that you got this problem solved.